# echo <<<HTML in PHP

Tags: php, echo

I need to work with some scripts, in which I found this:

```
$data = <<<DATA
MIN={$min}
INVOICE={$invoice}
AMOUNT={$sum}
EXP_TIME={$exp_date}
DESCR={$descr}
DATA;
```

Can someone provide more info around `$somevar = <<<DATA`... and `echo <<<HTML`... it seems hard to find useful info about this.

Comment: In some IDEs the code you use after the `<<<` can even tell the IDE to syntax highlight and lint the code using the rules associated with that code. For example `<<<SQL` would be treated as SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It´s a heredoc syntax:

> Heredoc

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line. Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

You can read more about this in the php documentation
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

More info:

Example:

```
<?php
$mystring = <<<EOT
This is some PHP text.
It is completely free
I can use "double quotes"
and 'single quotes',
plus $variables too, which will
be properly converted to their values,
you can even type EOT, as long as it
is not alone on a line, like this:
EOT;
?>
```

> There are several key things to note about heredoc, and the example above:

> You can use anything you like; "EOT" is just an example

> You need to use <<< before the delimiter to tell PHP you want to enter heredoc mode

> Variable substitution is used in PHP, which means you do need to escape dollar symbols - if you do not, PHP will attempt variable replacement.

> You can use your delimiter anywhere in the text, but not in the first column of a new line

> At the end of the string, just type the delimiter with no spaces around it, followed by a semi-colon to end the statement

> Without heredoc syntax, complicated string assignments can quickly become very messy. Heredoc is not used all that often in the wild - very often you will wish it were used more, because too many scripts you will come across have messy code as a result of not using heredoc!

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3

Answer (score 6):

http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

which says:
*A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.*

Answer (score 1):

This is called Heredoc, you can specify an identifier and then use this instead of Double quoted strings so you wont need to escape double quotes because you already have a different delimiter for your string anymore. It has same escape rules and parsing rules with double-quoted strings (e.g \n, \r,variable parsing etc.) but you don't need to escape a double-quote while using Heredoc syntax.

`{$desc}` part is curly syntax, which is a complex way to parsing variables in a string. Complex doesn't means hard to write. Complex means you can have more options to parse a variable (e.g you can assign a returning value from a function as a variable name and then parse that variable etc.)

For more information about heredoc and curly syntax look here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc